# Redis delete by pattern is too slow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, lua, redis

```
  for i, name in ipairs(redis.call('KEYS''cache:user_transaction_logs:*:8866666')) do redis.call('DEL', name); end"
```

How can I Optimise this redis query?

We are using Redis as cache store in Rails.Whenever auser makes a successfull transaction The receivers and  initiators transaction history is expired from redis

Comment: a small optimization can be sending multiple keys in DEL, but the major bottle-neck here is KEYS command.

Answer (score 7):

The query can not be optimized - it should be replaced in its entirety because the use of `KEYS` is discouraged for anything other than debugging purposes on non-production environments.

A preferable approach, instead of trying to fetch the relevant key names ad-hoc, is to manage them in a data structure (e.g. Set or List) and read from it when you perform the deletions.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the approach for how you are storing cache entries for your users.
Your keys should look something like `cache:user_transaction_logs:{user_id}`.
Then you will be able to just delete the entry by its key (user_id).

In case if you need several cache entries per user_id - use Redis hashes (https://redis.io/commands#hash), and then again you will be able to delete all entries per user_id with one command `DELETE` or needed entry with `HDEL`.

Also a good idea to use Redis database numbers (default 0, 1-15 available) and put separate functionalities on separate database numbers. Then in case if you need to wipe cache of whole functionality that can be done with one command `FLUSHDB`